# Image not displayed when run ASP.NET directly from Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I built an ASP.NET MVC web application from template in Visual Studio 2019. I have copied some `.png` files into a new folder - `images` - and copied it underneath my project folder.

I modify my `.cshtml` file added in `<img src="~/images/img1.png" />`, but when I run directly from the IDE, the image does not show up. Why?

I have tried below

- copy images folder to different places, such as App_Data, Content, Views
- Change the cshtml to be

  - `<img src="~/Content/images/img1.png" />`
  - `<img src="~/images/img1.png" />`
  - `<img src="~/img1.png" />`
  - `<img src="img1.png" />`

I also tried to change the property of the file

- Build -> Resource
- Copy to Output -> Always

None of them works.

Help!

Comment: Can you open developer tools in your browser and see the path you are trying to access.

Comment: OMG, I think there is something wrong with the Edge. when I click on the Settings and more, it crashed. Then I tried to open it with IE, I am able to see the images!!!

Comment: :( …. waste me half an hour. IE works fine. This is my first attempt on build a web app, lack of experience...

Answer (score 0):

You can do following steps in order to resolve your problem:

1) First you need to check if the files copied in new folder are included in your project. If not then, in visual studio, right click your files and select include into the project.

2) Secondly, you can check into the browser console which you will find in developer tools of the browser. Then you will be able to find out the root cause of the problem..